# What does it mean to "store" objects in a class?

Tags: java

I am working on a Java homework assignment that says:

> The programming projects of Chapter 4 discussed a Card class that represents a standard playing card. Create a class called DeckofCards that stores 52 objects of the Card class. Include methods to shuffle the deck, deal a card, and report the number of cards left in the deck. The shuffle method should assume you have a full deck. Create a driver class with a main method that deals each card from a shuffled deck, printing each card as it is dealt.

Where it says

> Create a class called DeckofCards that stores 52 objects of the Card class.

I am not sure of what that means to store something. Would it mean to create 52 objects into a class? Or, assuming that 52 objects are already made in the Card class, put all those objects in another object or constructor? I did make a card class, however, I did not make 52 objects, also there are 52 cards in a card deck so I am assuming 52 objects is the same as 52 cards. Anyways, if needed, here is the code for my card class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CardClass {

    private static Random generator = new Random();
    private int suit, num;
    private String cardSuit, cardNum;

    public CardClass() {
        shuffle();
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        num = generator.nextInt(13) + 1; 
        suit = generator.nextInt(4) + 1; 
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (num >=2 && num <= 10)
            cardNum = Integer.toString(num);
        else if (num == 1)
            cardNum = "Ace";
        else if (num == 11)
            cardNum = "Jack";
        else if (num == 12)
            cardNum = "Queen";
        else 
            cardNum = "King";

        if (suit == 1)
            cardSuit = "Spades";
        else if (suit == 2)
            cardSuit = "Hearts";
        else if (suit == 3)
            cardSuit = "Clubs";
        else 
            cardSuit = "Diamonds";

        return cardNum + " of " + cardSuit;     
    }
}
```

This is also my very first on this community so I apologize for any mistakes I made and thank you very much in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that your DeckOfCards class should contain an array of size 52 that stores Card instances. You could always use another data structure like a linked list. The array should probably be a private property in DeckOfCards, like

```
private Card cards[]=new Card[52];
```

Then you fill the array with Card object as such:

```
for(int i=0;i<52;i++){
    int cardType=i/13;
    String type="Heart";
    if(cardType==0)type="Spades";
    else if(cardType==1)type="Clubs";
    else if(cardType==2)type="Diamond";
    cards[i]=new Card(i, cardType);
}
```

Also you would probably be best off asking programming questions in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to think about this is you're assigning values to the variables (attributes) of a class. Even if you have multiple objects of the same class, each class will have its own random values for those variables since you're using the `Random` class.

For an example using your code, you can have two `CardClass` objects, so they both have `cardSuit` and `cardNum` variables, but the `cardSuit` and `cardNum` variables will be different for both objects since they're independent of each other because you stored the values to the unique class objects.

So with your question, it seems like you're being asked to store 52 values (the values that make up a standard deck of cards) into an array.

Answer (score 1):

You might think of a class as a *blueprint* for an object. An object is always an instance of a class. Objects can hold other objects of the same class or of a different class:

```
class A {
    private B someInstanceOfB;
}
```

Now the `Card` class should only contain the suit (clubs, diamonds, spades and hearts) and the value 2 through 10 and J, Q, K and A. (In fact, this is an ideal case to use `enum`s, but for simplicity, I will not use them.)

The `Deck` contains indeed an array of 52 `Card` objects. Note that you may not deal twice the same card, so we need to have the possibility to remove cards from the deck. The `ArrayList` class allows us to do so:

```
class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>;
}
```

*(The angle brackets you see, is usage of Generics. You will learn about it later. For now, it means an `ArrayList` containing objects of the `Card` type.)*

Now you need something to fill the array. Robin's method to fill the array is not quite good, since their values range from 0 to 51. Instead, you should use something like this:

```
class Deck {

    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public Deck() {
        // Let's assume that 0=clubs, 1=diamonds, 2=spades, 3=hearts
        for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
            // For each suit, we add 13 cards with values 1 through 13.
            for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++) {
                this.cards.add(new Card(suit, value));
            }
        }
        // We did not yet shuffle the cards,
        //but `Collections.shuffle()` can do the job.
    }

    public void dealRandom() {
        // Pick one of the left cards,
        // remove it from the deck
        // and return it.
    }
}
```

Note that the `Card` class should not shuffle the cards, that's a responsability for the `Deck`. Also, we used integers as card type (suit) and integers for values. Printing a human-readable text to describe the card can be delegated to the `toString()` method.

Comment: When declare `private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();` the compiler says "can not find symbol - List", Thank you very much btw for your detailed post.

Comment: Well, of course you need to import the appropriate classes. Both classes can be found in the `java.util` package. By the way, which editor are you using?